# React/TypeScript - Extending component with generic type and reuse generic type within component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I have the following component that takes a generic `node` and `patchCurrentNode` props.

```
import { css } from '@emotion/react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import React, {
  PropsWithChildren,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import BaseNodeData from '../../types/BaseNodeData';
import { PatchCurrentNode } from '../../types/BaseNodeProps';

type Props<NodeData extends BaseNodeData = BaseNodeData> = {
  node: NodeData;
  patchCurrentNode: PatchCurrentNode<NodeData>;
};

/**
 * Input that stores the name of the node's selected value.
 *
 * Some nodes ask for an input (text, choice, etc.), the selected value will be stored and be indexed using the selected variable's name.
 */
export const VariableNameInput: <NodeData extends BaseNodeData = BaseNodeData>(p: PropsWithChildren<Props<NodeData>>) => React.ReactElement = (props) => {
  const {
    node,
    patchCurrentNode,
  } = props;
  const {
    width = 200,

  } = node;
  console.log('node', node);
  const [variableName, setVariableName] = useState<string | undefined>(node?.data?.variableName);
  console.log('VariableNameInput variableName', variableName);

  const onChange = (event: any) => {
    console.log('onChange variableName', event, event?.target?.value);
    setVariableName(event?.target?.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log('onSubmit variableName', variableName);
    patchCurrentNode({
      data: {
        variableName: variableName,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={'variable-name-container'}
      css={css`
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: black;
        width: ${width}px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;

        .variable-name {
          width: ${width - 50}px;
          margin-top: 12px;
          margin-left: -5px;
          padding-left: 5px;
          background-color: black;
          color: ${variableName?.length ? 'white' : '#6E6E6E'}; // Change different color between placeholder and actual value
          border: 1px solid #6E6E6E;
        }

        .submit {
          color: #6E6E6E;
          margin-left: 10px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      `}
    >
      <input
        className={'variable-name'}
        placeholder={'Variable name'}
        value={variableName}
        onChange={onChange}
      />

      <FontAwesomeIcon
        className={'submit'}
        icon={['fas', 'paper-plane']}
        onClick={onSubmit}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VariableNameInput;
```

It is used like this:

<VariableNameInput
node={node}
patchCurrentNode={patchCurrentNode}
/>

With the following types:

```
import BaseNodeData from '../BaseNodeData';
import { QuestionNodeAdditionalData } from './QuestionNodeAdditionalData';

export type QuestionNodeData = BaseNodeData<QuestionNodeAdditionalData>;

---

import BaseNodeAdditionalData from '../BaseNodeAdditionalData';
import { QuestionChoiceType } from './QuestionChoiceType';

export type QuestionNodeAdditionalData = BaseNodeAdditionalData & {
  text?: string;
  questionType?: QuestionChoiceType;
  variableName?: string;
};
```

The implementation of the generic in the component works. But, I still have TS errors:
[image]

[image]

---

How can I reuse the generic `NodeData` type in the component's implementation?

I was thinking I could do something like `node?.data?.variableName as NodeData`, but `NodeData` isn't known there.

[image]

---

**Edit**: [Solution](https://github.com/Vadorequest/poc-nextjs-reaflow/commit/aa384e3b2657c3218253b376959d1405e30ee824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't getting access to the generic `NodeData` inside of the component body due to how you have defined the component's type signature separately from it's implementation.

```
export const VariableNameInput: <NodeData extends BaseNodeData = BaseNodeData>(
  p: PropsWithChildren<Props<NodeData>>
) => React.ReactElement = (props) => {
  // ...
};
```

Instead of applying the type annotations to the `VariableNameInput` variable, apply them directly to the function arguments and return type.

```
export const VariableNameInput = <NodeData extends BaseNodeData = BaseNodeData>(
  props: PropsWithChildren<Props<NodeData>>
): React.ReactElement => {
  // ...
};
```

You are now able to access `NodeData` inside the component.

```
useState<string | undefined>((node as NodeData).data?.variableName);
```

But you don't get any additional information by asserting this since `node` is a required prop and it is always type `NodeData`.

It seems more likely that you need to define `variableName` as an optional `string` prop on the `BaseNodeAdditionalData` type.  If you edit your post to include the types for `BaseNodeData` and `PatchCurrentNode` (and their dependencies) then perhaps I can help you fix the underlying issues.

It's the callback `patchCurrentNode` that is going to give you the most trouble because `NodeData` could extend `BaseNodeData` by requiring additional properties or more specific values.  You can assert `as Partial<NodeData>`, but you want to be confident that any assertion you make is actually correct.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/yNaayN)

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, your analysis is correct. I'm unsure whether it is "best" to write the TS type for the function itself, or for the `props` property directly. I usually do it on the function, but it doesn't seem to work in this case. Here's what I came up with by playing around a bit: `export const VariableNameInput: React.FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<Props>> = <NodeData extends BaseNodeData = BaseNodeData>(props: PropsWithChildren<Props<NodeData>>): React.ReactElement => {}`. But the `React.FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<Props>>` feels duplicated and unnecessary.

Comment: Some of it is just preference, but personally I would not apply any type to the component itself.  If the function arguments and return are typed then it's not necessary.  `React.FunctionComponent` doesn't work with generic components, so just type the function itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't define the `variableName` in the `BaseNodeData`, because `BaseNodeData` is a generic "NodeData" type, which is being augmented by specialized types. I guess in this case my only solution is to create a new `NodeDataWithVariableName` (or similar) and use it instead of `BaseNodeData` in the `VariableNameInput` component.

Comment: I think that would be good.  If your component expects that you have a node type with a `variableName` property then you should require that from your props.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Linda, I was able to find a solution. I bet it can be improved/simplified but that'll do for now! https://github.com/Vadorequest/poc-nextjs-reaflow/commit/aa384e3b2657c3218253b376959d1405e30ee824

Comment: I'm thinking about it and `patchCurrentNode` always gets called with `{ data: { variableName: string } }` no matter what `NodeData` is.  So I think that the `patchCurrentNode` prop should just be a function that accepts that argument rather than a generic that depends on `NodeData`.